# vue component not rendering the data it gets from the backend

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a very basic HTML page with a simple Vue component. In the network tab I can see it gets the data correctly, the list where it should appear is rendered, but the data is simply not there.

```
    <div id="app">
      <h2>Total inventory: {{ totalProducts }}</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>beginning of the list</li>
        <li v-for="product in products">
          {{ product.name }} {{ product.price }}
        </li>
        <li>End of the list</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
      const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          products: []
        },
        created () {
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/teddies')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
              this.products = json.products
            })
        },
        computed () {
          return this.products.reduce((sum, product) => {
            return sum + product.quantity
          }, 0)
        }
      })
    </script>
```

I tried including the script's code into a separate file, using axios for the request (I knew it wouldn't change a thing because the request actually works already), attributing an ID directly to the list and using that in the script... nothing appeared in place of {{ product.name }} and {{ product.price }}  . Same goes for the totalProducts variable and {{ totalProducts }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `json` directly to `this.products` like :

```
 fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
              this.products = json           
            })
```

because `json` represents the `products` list, so `json.products` will return `undefined`

and the computed property should be defined as follows :

```
computed:{
  comp1(){...},
 comp2(){...}
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>Total inventory: {{ totalProducts }}</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>beginning of the list</li>
    <li v-for="product in products">
      {{ product.title }} {{ product.price }}
    </li>
    <li>End of the list</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

      products: []

    },
    created() {
      fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(prod => {

          this.products = prod
         
        })
    },
    computed: {
      totalProducts() {
        return this.products.reduce((sum, product) => {
          return sum + product.price
        }, 0)
      }
    }

  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You data should return a function that returns a new object:

Short way

```
data: () => ({
   products: []
})
```

Long way

```
data() {
  return {
    products: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I checked a few article and got the logic behind your answer, thank you a lot. On its own it didn't make my code work but I strongly appreciate what you made me understand

Comment: I had actually forgotten to +1 your answer...